# Elasticsearch ActiveMQ River Configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, activemq-classic

I start to configure an ActiveMQ river, I'm already installed the ([ActiveMQ plugin](https://github.com/domdorn/elasticsearch-river-activemq)) but I feel confused about how to make it working, the documentation was so brief, Actually, I follow exactly the steps of creating a new river but I don't know what are the following steps to follow?

**Note:**

1. I have the an ActiveMQ server up and running and I tested it using a
   simple JMS app to push a message into a queue.
2. I created a new river using:

   ```
   curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/myindex_river/_meta' -d '{
     "type" : "activemq",
     "activemq" : {
         "user" : "guest",
         "pass" : "guest",
         "brokerUrl" : "failover://tcp://localhost:61616",
         "sourceType" : "queue",
         "sourceName" : "elasticsearch",
         "consumerName" : "activemq_elasticsearch_river_myindex_river",
         "durable" : false,
         "filter" : ""
     },
     "index" : {
          "bulk_size" : 100,
          "bulk_timeout" : "10ms"
     }
   }'
   ```
3. After creating the previous river, I could get it's status using
   `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_status'`, it give me the index
   status, not the created river.

Please, any help to get me the right road with ActiveMQ river configuration with the elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

I told you on the mailing list. Define `index.index` value or set the name of your river to be your index name (easier):

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_index/_meta' -d '
{
  "type":"activemq",
  "activemq":{
    "user":"guest",
    "pass":"guest",
    "brokerUrl":"failover://tcp://localhost:61616",
    "sourceType":"queue",
    "sourceName":"elasticsearch",
    "consumerName":"activemq_elasticsearch_river_myindex_river",
    "durable":false,
    "filter":""
  },
  "index":{
    "bulk_size":100,
    "bulk_timeout":"10ms"
  }
}'
```

or

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/myindex_river/_meta' -d '
{
  "type":"activemq",
  "activemq":{
    "user":"guest",
    "pass":"guest",
    "brokerUrl":"failover://tcp://localhost:61616",
    "sourceType":"queue",
    "sourceName":"elasticsearch",
    "consumerName":"activemq_elasticsearch_river_myindex_river",
    "durable":false,
    "filter":""
  },
  "index":{
    "index":"my_index",
    "bulk_size":100,
    "bulk_timeout":"10ms"
  }
}'
```

It should help.

If not, update your question with what you can see in logs.